# Distribute a MySQL protocol?

Tags: mysql, lua

I don't know much about MySQL, so I figured I might as well see if it's possible to do what I want before going off and learning it.

I want to know if it's possible to distribute a software and have that software send/receive data from a database in MySQL.

So say they're making a username and password from a distributed application, is it possible to use that information on my server?

Comment: If the application uses MySQL client libraries, then it can connect to your server as a client, yes (if you grant permission). Usually though, you woudl _not_ want to give access directly to your server. Instead you should create a web service which accepts usernames and passwords.  Allowing direct connections from clients you are not in control of is a nightmare scenario for security.

Comment: I'm just trying to transfer data an app collects and send it to my database, any super secure ways of doing so?

Comment: The secure way is to receive the data from some server-side code.  If your database is open and accepting connections, then really it cannot know whether or not your application sent the data and anyone could send anything unfiltered. You need server-side code in between to receive and sanitize it before insertion. That's usually done with some sort of web service that accepts http requests.

Answer (score 2):

You never want to distribute an app that contains a username / password combination.

If I am correctly understanding what you are asking, my course of action would to be to create a single mySQL user with restricted permissions and create PHP scripts to do your Database Access, using HTTP responses to send and receive the data you need.

This method is a lot less prone to attacks on your server.

Examples:

> http://www.example.com/apps/script.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
    print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table"));
?>
```

Here, your app would send a request to the above URL, and the contents of the table will be printed in raw text. You should then design your app to parse the response however you need it to.

Comment: How about if it's nonsensitive data? Would it be possible to shoot that information from the source to my database?

Comment: Sensitive or non-sensitive, any app can be disassembled, that being said, you give my your app which communicates with the server, I could extract your Database Host, Username, and Password, and then attack it in a variety of ways..

Comment: You seem to be pretty good with this whole secure connection thing. Any good tutorials online i can read relating to this subject with php and http?

Comment: What language is your app going to be written in?

Comment: At the moment, simple Lua with binaries like iup. And no i am not joking, lol.

Comment: I do not know `lua` however the basics are still the same, on your server create a PHP script to handle the database stuff, and in your app, (search how to do it as I am not sure) sent requests to the URL of the script sending POST/GET data, and execute different database queries according to what you need done. I would try and be of more assistance, but as stated, I do not know lua ^.^

Comment: Now, just one more question, would I need to purchase anything to use PHP for the client to server interaction?

Comment: Where do you run your MySQL Database? The PHP Scripts run just like you would run a regular website. If you are on a Shared Host, you will have access to PHP.